# How can I get the submit button to be on the same line as the form field?

Tags: html, css

I want to have my submit button to the right of my search form. But I also want to keep my label above the form field. So it's Label, then on a new line the field with the search button on the same line.

```
<div class="searchForm">
<form id="UserDisplayForm" method="post" action="/sponster/users/display" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>
<div class="input text"><label for="UserSearchForAFriend'sPage">Search For A Friend's Page</label><input name="data[User][Search for a friend's page]" type="text" id="UserSearchForAFriend&#039;sPage" /></div>
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Search" /></div></form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing any of your markup:

```
#UserDisplayForm label { display: block; }
#UserDisplayForm div { display: inline-block; }
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/3rTbm/).  I've assumed you want the styles to apply only within your form, hence I've prefixed the rules with `#UserDisplayForm`.

Comment: @helenhighwater Yep, won't work in IE7 which doesn't support `inline-block`, but [there is a hack you can use if you need IE7 support](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<label...>` and `<input...>` tags inside `<span...>` instead of `<div...>`

Comment: That didn't work either :( this is really frustrating. I've been trying to do this one little thing for four hours now!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something simple like:

```
<... previous elements ...>
<div class="row"> <!-- this is semantically a "form row" -->
   <label style="display: block" ...></label>
   <input type="text"...>
   <input type="submit" ...>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, I changed my <div class="searchForm"> to your <div class="row"> and added the style for the label in the style sheet but it didn't make any difference. Is there meant to be some other styles for .row?

Comment: The row is merely a container (so you can add a margin-bottom to every row of the form, for example). The "display: block" for the label makes the next two inline elements go on a new line. The two inline elements (the inputs) naturally flows one after the other. If I understand correctly your problem, this pretty much solves it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ting to do is to change the inner **div** tags to **span** tags and add a **br** break to get to the next line..  :)

```
<div class="searchForm">
    <form id="UserDisplayForm" method="post" action="/sponster/users/display"
            accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
        </div>
        <span class="input text">
            <label for="UserSearchForAFriend'sPage">Search For A Friend's Page
            </label>
            <br>
            <input name="data[User][Search for a friend's page]" type="text" 
                    id="UserSearchForAFriend&#039;sPage" />
        </span>

        <span class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Search" /></span>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Or else you could make the label reside in a separate **div** tag and the **textbox** and **button** in separate **span** tags as shown below.

Search For A Friend's Page

Answer (score 0):

Try this stylesheet:

```
.searchForm {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 150px; /* whatever width you want it to be */
}
    .searchForm .input {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        width: 100px; /* whatever width you want it to be */
    }
        .searchForm .input label { display: none; /* generally people don't want their label showing when making a search field */
        .searchForm .input input { display: block; ... and any other styles ... */

    .searchForm .submit {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        width: 30px; /* again, whatever width you want it */;
    }
```

This is making the `<div>`'s float properly. You **do not** have to put them in `<span>`'s to make it work, that's just lazy coding. 
Chuck in your widths in the styles to whatever you want them to be, and it should work. It really depends on the rest of your code/css.

Good luck!